# Font does not applying React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating a `@font-face` in index.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Raleway";
    src: url(../assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-VariableFont_wght.ttf) format(truetype),
}
```

Then setting `font-family` in `body`:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

index.css is imported inside `index.js` but font still does not applying to the body.

Comment: Remove the trailing comma from your URL. If you don't have multiple file urls a comma at the end will break the property. As always:  If you still don't see your font applied - check your devtools/network tab for loaded font files or 404 logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file try:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Raleway";
  src: local("Raleway"),
       url(../assets/fonts/Raleway/Raleway-VariableFont_wght.ttf) 
       format(truetype),
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Component example:

```js
import React from "react"

// CSS File
import "index.css"

const So74327630 = (props) => <div>Example</div>

export default So74327630
```

Good reference if using Create React App: "[Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)"